# why do we skip mizmor l'toda on pesach but still bring the sacrifice with our lips in eyzeh mekoman?

Tags: passover, shacharis-morning-prayer, korban, chametz-leaven

I am told we don't say mizmor l'toda (psalm 100) on pesach as the loaves of the sacrifice are chametz. However I believe we still say the laws of the toda in 'eyzeh mekoman' in the section of the prayer known as korbanos (sacrifices).

this is troubling because the psalm is merely an allusion to offering the sacrifice, whereas the laws of a sacrifice are supposed to be considered as if we offered the sacrifice itself when we don't have a temple and cannot offer them physically.

so, how can we offer the toda sacrifice on pesach when it contains leaven loaves?

Comment: According to Ashkenazim. It appears that Sephardim DO say the Mizmor. http://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/korban-todah/

Answer (score 5):

We say the mishna of Eizehu Mekomon so that everyone should learn some mishnayos every day (Shulchan Aruch siman 50). This reasoning applies even when we can't bring some of the korbanos (such as on shabbos or yom tov).

However, after the korbanos yochid, the minhag is to say a yehi ratzon that it should be considered as if the person actually brought the korban. That indeed, one shouldn't say on days that you can't bring that particular korban (such as the toda on erev pesach)

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question - it makes the question even more problematic.

Comment: How exactly does it make the question more problematic?

Comment: @DannySchoemann ^

Answer (score 3):

The Eizehu Mekoman is not *bringing* the korban, but teaching us how the bais hamikdash will be set up. It gives a list and instructions for **all** korbanos, and the *bringing* on that day does not apply. Thus we see the list includes every type of korban rather than just those being brought on this particular day.

The Mizmor LeTodah, on the other hand, is indeed said **because** we cannot bring it now (though we will in the future bimheirah beyameinu) which is why we do not say it on Erev Yom Kipur, Erev Pesach, and Chol Hamoed Pesach. This is what we are saying in order to make it **as if** we are bringing it today.